# Change data in appdata database file on windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an aplication using local database (I have filled it with the data) and deploy it to emulator. When initializing application I copy db from installation folder to the root of the isolated storage container. That works fine and I can use all data. But I need to change (insert, update and delete) some data and want to save those changes into appdata file in installation folder so next time when I run emulator I can see the changes.

What is the best solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the WP7 Isolated Storage Explorer http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/ in order to download you sdf file from emulator to your local machine and then add it again to your appdata folder.

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?